# SASS create attribute dynamically by other attribute value

Tags: css, sass, attributes, dynamically-generated

I want to create an attribute depending on the value of an other attribute.

The `data-active-nav` will be set dynamically, so for an example we have:

HTML:

```
<div data-active-nav="user">
    <div data-nav="user"></div>
    <div data-nav="admin"></div>
</div>
```

Now I want to style the inner div's depending on the attribute, but I don't want to write a style for each.

I want something like this:

```
[data-nav=#{attr(data-active-nav)}] {
    color: black;
}
```

But the output of this will be

```
[data-nav='attr(data-active-nav)']
```

Is there a way to do this, without writing

```
[data-active-nav=user] {
    [data-nav=user] {
        color: black;
    }
}

[data-active-nav=admin] {
    [data-nav=admin] {
        color: black;
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Sass has no way of knowing anything about your dom. 
Sass is a preprocessor, this mean that it generate pure CSS, it is not a dynamic language.

this mean that sass cannot figure out the value off a data-attribute. Only CSS can.

In CSS I think that you can only use, `attr()` for a property value, and even this is experimental, and will not be widely supported by the browsers. Today, it's only pretty safe to use it in `content` property for a `pseudo-element`.

so the short answer is no, you cannot.

In the other hand, I don't see why you are trying to style éléments using data attributes since there goal is to store data, and not determine style… 
Also, they are slower selectors than classes. but I guess it's not the subject.

I would recommend :

```
<nav class="nav is-user-active">
    <div class="nav__item nav__item--user">user</div>
    <div class="nav__item nav__item--other">other</div>
</nav>
```

sass (in BEM fashion):

```
.nav__item {
   color: blue;

   .is-user-active &--user,
   .is-other-active &--other {
       color: black;
   }
}
```

this will compile into :

```
.nav__item {
   color: blue;
}

.is-user-active .nav__item--user,
.is-other-active .nav__item--other {
    color: black;
}
```

but if you really want to use `data-attr`, you can folow the same pattern:

```
   [data-nav-active="user"] [nav-item="user"],
   [data-nav-active="other"] [nav-item="other"] {
       color: black;
   }
```

Comment: it would be like 15 classes for me to write, that's why i wanted to know, if there is a way to generate that with the data attribute. but I think, that I have to write them :)